# HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode() results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, http, url

I'm currently trying to access a web API (not mine) located under https://fnbr.co/api/shop.

The code I am running is basically this:

```
URL url = new URL("https://fnbr.co/api/shop");

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
writer.flush();

System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode()); // second error

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); // first error

// read from this reader
```

Console output (the response code) is

> 404
>
> FileNotFoundException: https://fnbr.co/api/shop

at the line with `conn.getInputStream()` and an another

> FileNotFoundException: https://fnbr.co/api/shop

in the line with `conn.getResponseCode()`

Where is my problem (because 404 should mean that the file doesn't exist, but I can access it via my browser)?

Comment: does you browser use a proxy?

Comment: @jhamon no but i don t have a problem with the browser, but with the java code

Comment: I got that, the implicit part of my question was: maybe you didn't set the proxy in your code.

Comment: is this java code executed from the same system where you are getting response when accessed using browser?

Comment: @Samy yes i use the same system

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 404 means that the requested URL does not exist. That means in your case that there is nothing behind GET https://fnbr.co/api/shop address. Maybe you need to use different protocol like PUT, POST, etc.:

> 404 Not Found The requested resource could not be found but may be
>   available in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are
>   permissible.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) is the official description of the HTTP response codes.

You need to handle errors in your client code, like HTTP 404 so you can read the response (keep in mind that it is not file, it is a request-response!) if you get back HTTP 200, like this:

```
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
}
```

Comment: I have to use GET because that is so prescribed in the API

Comment: Check whether your URL correct or not. It is easy because it is a GET request. Try to open https://fnbr.co/api/shop in your web browser.

Comment: it is possible for me to successfully open the url in the web browser - it even gives the result I want. But it java is giving me a 404 error for the *same* url

Comment: @writzlpfrimpft Handling response code solved 404 resource unavailable ? Kindly clarify.

Comment: @Samy I am getting a 404 error code even though the resource *is available* (I can access it through my web browser)

Comment: Mayby you missed something from the HTTP header. Check the HTTP traffic with eg. FireBug in your web browser and then write a Java code which makes exact the same request as your web browser (headers, cookies, message body, etc.).

Comment: @zappee but i wouldnt get error 404 and filenotfoundexception if i missed something of the header right?

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

and

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
writer.flush();
```

This looks bogus for a GET request.